# Running a process in a new terminal window within a vm

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, vagrant, virtual-machine

I'm wondering - is it possible to make a bash/shell process run, in a second terminal window, within a vagrant VM?

On my local machine, I can run the following in my bash script...

```
open -a Terminal -n "`pwd`" ## To launch a new window in the same dir

open -a Terminal -n "`pwd`" script.sh ## To launch a new window and run a script...
```

Up pops a new window - not with the same shell themes etc, but I can live with that.

However, if I jump into my vagrant box / VM or try to run it during a vagrant provision I get the following error:

```
open: invalid option -- 'a'
Usage: open [OPTIONS] -- command

This utility help you to start a program on a new virtual terminal (VT).

Options:
  -c, --console=NUM   use the given VT number;
  -e, --exec          execute the command, without forking;
  -f, --force         force opening a VT without checking;
  -l, --login         make the command a login shell;
  -u, --user          figure out the owner of the current VT;
  -s, --switch        switch to the new VT;
  -w, --wait          wait for command to complete;
  -v, --verbose       print a message for each action;
  -V, --version       print program version and exit;
  -h, --help          output a brief help message.
```

I may need to install something on the VM - but the fact that it recognises 'Open' means I'm not sure what or what would be best, and the help message wasn't useful

I've tried playing around with different options -e etc, but couldn't find anyone asking about this specifically within a VM environment.

Not tested on anything other than Mac OS Catalina, but...

- It would be great to have something that also worked cross platform.
- Is it possible to inherit the same terminal window settings (i.e. open a new tab in terminal, rather than open the default seperate terminal window...
- And it would be interesting to know how to use the "Alternative Window" which in terminal at least can be activated by command+shift+down ... ideally in a reliable way
- I should also say - At the moment (at least) I then need to revert BACK to the original terminal window and leave this other one running in the background, so I don't want to use -s.

I've also tried the below which I couldn't get to work, but may be a useful reference for others thinking about opening terminal windows from their scripts...

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "cd ~/somewhere"'
gnome-terminal # not found
xterm # not found
konsole # not found
```

Answer (score 0):

you can read https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253531 but `open` is a Mac-os specific command that has no equivalent in your VM, you don't precise what you're running (ubuntu, centos ....)

what are you really trying to achieve ? if you want to run a script to install a software, you can just call the script.

Comment: I was hoping to load some file watchers on my projects automatically; I currently have them running at the end of my vagrant booting up process, but then I need to open another window to ssh in. It's only a small thing but it made me wonder

Comment: right ... a bit overhead then but you could open a tmux session and create multiple panes for each of your watchers, still it would be in a single ssh session